# GIT - Errors when executing git init

Tags: windows, git

When executing `git init` in GitBash, in a Windows VM, one developer had the following errors:

1. 1st instance

   ```
   error: could not write config file //xxx/yyy/.git/config: Function not implemented
   Fatal: could not set 'core.symlinks' to false
   ```
2. 2nd instance

   ```
   error: could not write config file //xxx/yyy/.git/config: Function not implemented
   Fatal: could not set 'core.repositoryformatversion' to '0'
   ```

However, another developer in the same VM had no issues. 
He is able to execute `git init`, `git add`, `git commit` & `git push`.

Please help if you had the same issues and discovered the solution.

Comment: The *function not implemented* error is coming from a file-system operation (open, write, or close system call). This suggests that the VM setup is wrong and the computer is refusing to write files in that VM for some reason. Git itself can't get the reason; you'll have to look elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

***This is usually caused by permission error.***

And thus it makes sense that one developer is able to use git while the other one isn't.
Check your folder (git repository folder) permissions and verify that the given user is able to write content to this folder. (check the permissions on the given folder and its parent)

Another option (**might be but less likely**) is that the antivirus is blocking you from changing the folder

Comment: The user is able to deposit code and modify in the folder, and therefore could write. But when "git init" is executed, the error "could not write config file //xxx/yyy/.git/config: Function not implemented" then came up

Answer (score 0):

(to add to @CodeWizard's answer)

When creating a repo in a folder : git creates a `.git/` folder at the base of the directory, and then manipulates files in this folder.

- Check if this folder is indeed created (type `dir //xxx/yyy/.git` in a shell for example),
- check the access permissions ("Security" tab of the Properties window) on this `.git/` folder.

Comment: Hi LeGEC,  The .git folder was not created. I try executing , "chmod a+rwx " (where .git folder should reside), and then tried "git init" again. But the .git folder was not created, and the same error came up

Comment: The setup is on a Windows VM, I don't think chmod in git bash works as you expect. Check the access rights from the Windows system ("Properties" of the target folder)

Comment: We checked this morning, under Windows. The developer has full access. We recently had a malware attack. I am not sure if this is the cause. However, there was no problem for the 2nd developer on the same VM.

Answer (score 0):

When Trend Micro was disabled for the VM, the error disappeared. I am not sure why some folders did not have the error when Trend Micro was enabled. So probably Trend Micro had to be configured differently.